# Evaluating the integral: $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac{dx}{x^2+x+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Please help me in this integral:

> $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac{dx}{x^2+x+2}$$
>   I've tried as usually, but it seems tricky. Do You have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I've tried as usually* Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the integrand as

$$\frac{1}{\frac{7}{4}+(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}$$

so that the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{7}{4}+(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt7}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\Big|_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\left(\pi-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac1{x^2+x+2} = \dfrac1{\left(x+\dfrac12 \right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}2 \right)^2}$$
Recall that
$$\int_a^b \dfrac{dx}{(x+c)^2 + d^2} = \dfrac1d \left.\left(\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+c}d\right)\right)\right \vert_{a}^b$$
I trust you can finish it from here. You will also need to use the fact that
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \arctan(y) = \dfrac{\pi}2$$